# Would Drupal send to an alternative email address for reset password?

Tags: users, authentication-authorization

I am very new in Drupal.
I have an installation of Drupal 7 with LDAP authentication and LDAP user provision, this LDAP is linked to corporate mail system too. Users have 2 mail accounts (a corporate account and an alternative account), if a user forgot his password, I need the password reset send mail to both email addresses not only to the corporate account.

Answer (score 4):

You'll want to create a custom module, please see https://www.drupal.org/node/1074360

You can then implement hook_mail_alter().

```
/**
 * Implements hook_mail_alter().
 */
function my_module_mail_alter(&$message) {
  // Alter password reset
  if ($message['id'] == 'user_password_reset') {
    // Load the user by email address
    if ($user = user_load_by_mail($message['to'])) {
      // If you have another user field with their alternative email address, add to the $message array
      if (!empty($user->field_user_alt_mail)) {
        $message['to'] = $message['to'] . ', ' . $user->field_user_alt_mail[LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['value'];
      }
    }
  }
}
```

edit: changed 'password_reset' to 'user_password_reset' as per Paul's comment.

Comment: Please note, that `$message['id']` is actually `user_password_reset`. Alternatively, you can check `$message['key']` which is `password_reset`. Additionally, if an email field is used (instead of a simple text field), you need to call `$user->field_user_alt_mail[LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['email']` (it's email instead of value).